# What is the difference between tables and datasets?

Tags: matlab, dataset

in my MATLAB code I mostly use `dataset`s to store data and metadata of different types in a single container variable. However, I found out that coworkers use `table`s. It seems to me that the two data types are very similar: both can be accessed by column names or indices, both support the `summary` function, etc..

**What's the difference between the two data types?**

Comment: This has already been answered in a matlab central [discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103851-what-are-the-differences-between-dataset-and-table-in-matlab-8-2-r2013b)

Comment: @brodroll I included your link in my answer, as it basically says the same. I hope you're fine with it, otherwise I will delete again.

Comment: @thewaywewalk No problem at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without going into detail, `table` is a quite new function and comes with the basic Matlab. The older `dataset` however is part of the **Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox**.

The are quite similar, as you already know, though I can't tell you exactly *how* similar. But the [**doc**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) is actually clear on what you should use:

> The dataset data type might be removed in a future release. To work with heterogeneous data, use the MATLAB® table data type instead. See MATLAB table documentation for more information.

So `table` is meant to be the replacement function for `dataset` available for everybody. Just use `table` and you're safe for the future.

As mentioned by **brodroll** in the comments, there is also a [**statement of MathWorks on Matlab Central**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103851-what-are-the-differences-between-dataset-and-table-in-matlab-8-2-r2013b):

> Broadly speaking, Tables and datasets essentially serve the same
>   functionality. Following are some of the differences:
>
> 1) Tables are included as part of core MATLAB, and do not need the
>   installation of Statistics Toolbox to use them. Moreover, their design
>   and terminology makes them a bit more accessible for non-statistical
>   users, though they remain just as useful for statistics.
>
> 2) TABLE is ultimately meant to replace DATASET over time. Hence it is
>   recommended to use TABLE in place of DATASET. Please note that this
>   transition will not happen immediately and upcoming releases will
>   provide more details and strategies for making the transition.
>
> 3) You still need to use DATASET in the Statistics Toolbox while using
>   classes such as ‘LinearModel’ and ‘LinearMixedModel’ (which is new in
>   MATAB R2013b). It is recommended to use TABLE and converting to
>   DATASET only when needed, using TABLE2DATASET.
>
> 4) The TABLE class is currently sealed. Hence it is not possible to
>   subclass from it unlike the DATASET class which can be inherited by a
>   subclass.

Comment: Thanks! Quick and detailed answer. Good, it's out with the old `dataset`, and in with the new `table`, then!

Comment: From a quick inspection, the dataset codebase was basically ported to table.

Comment: `table` is [R2013b+](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btz8s39) I believe.